# how to remove just <i> and </i> from string in php

Tags: php, string

I want to remove `<i>` and `</i>` from a string.
I used `strip_tags` and `htmlentities`, but these are not a solution for me. because I will use that string for as **XML** source at the next step.
I could not change it by using `str_replace` and `preg_replace` also.

Comment: Your explanation of why strip_tags and str_replace won't work for you makes no sense.

Comment: Any idea as to why it's failing? - Me neither; show some code in order to see what you've tried.

Comment: Because they removed every tag in xml source

Comment: See the examples on Tizag.com => http://www.tizag.com/phpT/php-string-str_replace.php one of which I've successfully tested using both of your tags and replaced them with `<b>` and `</b>`, no problemo.

Comment: why don't `str_replace('<i>', '', $htmlstring)` and `str_replace('</i>', '', $htmlstring)` meet your needs?

Comment: I can't help you then, not without seeing your codes. See what Michael posted below, good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only wanting to replace both those tags then you could simply use str_replace.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$string = str_replace("<i>", "", "$string");
$string = str_replace("</i>", "", "$string");
```

Comment: You've got my full support on this, yet the OP states that *"I could not change it by using `str_replace` and `preg_replace` also."* Let's see if OP changes his/her mind.

Comment: My brain seemed to ignore that point, cheers Fred, hopefully this may help.

Comment: Cheers Michael. We'll sit and wait ;-)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed a probable scenario. OP's not showing code, so I haven't bothered submitting an "answer". It's anybody's guess at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

[strip_tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) actually will work for this if you have a list of the tags that you want to allow (that's its second argument).

You probably know your XML schema ahead of time, so you can use it like:

```
strip_tags($text, '<title><name>')
```

Then it will remove all the tags other than `title` and `name`...

`title` and `name` are just an example, obviously. You would include all the tags possible in your XML schema other than the ones you want to remove.

Comment: What if OP's code contains other wanted tags? This won't work.

Comment: @Fred -ii, Like I said, if you know your XML schema ahead of time it will work, and if you don't, it won't.